# Unexpected ; in my javascript I dont understand why

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added this bit of code and now I am getting an unexpected token";" error.

Code:

```
var i = 0;
var tabs = "";    
while(i < idArray.length){
tabs = tabs + "<a href='#' onclick='tabs('"+ idArray[i] +"')'>"+ idArray[i] +"</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;";
alert(tabs);
i++;
}
$("#editme").html(tabs);
```

I don't understand why.

Any ideas??

Thanks.

Comment: There is no syntax error in your code, the problem should be something else, http://jsfiddle.net/V9EA2/

Comment: On which line was that error thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

escape string in tabs() :

```
tabs = tabs + "<a href='#' onclick='tabs(\""+ idArray[i] +"\")'>"+ idArray[i] +"</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;";
                                          ^                ^
                                        here              here
```

Comment: Yup. That's it. `:)`. However, instead of removing the quotes, the solution would be to *escape* them. OP is using the quotes, so that a string value is passed to `tabs`. Therefore: `"<a href='#' onclick='tabs(\""+ idArray[i] +"\")'>"`. This seems like an anti-pattern, though. I recommend a templating engine (e.g. Handlebars).

Comment: @mgraph what if the `idArray` contains `strings`?

Comment: @m.abbas `idArray[i]` probably *is* a string. But when you do `'tabs(' + idArray[i] + ')'`, the result is `'tabs(theString)'`. You have to do `'tabs("' + idArray[i] + '")'`, to generate `'tabs("theString")'`, so that the `tabs` function receives a string which has the same value as the original `idArray[i]` string.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas yes i know but i am just asking because the first solution proposed would be false if idArray[i] was a string, but now it is ok with adding double quotes and escaping them.

Comment: @m.abbas Ah, my mistake. I thought that your comment was a reply to my comment.